# My Calendar control is cut

Tags: calendar, controls, foreground

I've got an own control with a calendar popup and other functionality.

I've placed that Control into a grid in the content of another Page.

My problem now is, that the Calendar Control is cut. So i only see half of the calendar. How can i bring it to the Front? Like the normal DatePicker Control does??

**Update:**

What I'm trying to build is a something like the `DatePickerControl` but with more functionality. It doesn't look so bad so far, the control itself works fine, but implemented into a content area it cuts the calendar control. The calendar control should be visible when a textbox has the focus,what I need to find, is a way to put the calendar to the front to create an overlay for the control. If someone has an idea about how to do it I'd appreciate it.

Comment: Calendar control... which one? What language?

Answer (score 0):

If its a calendar control used in grid of asp.net then specify a fixed size to your calendar control and accordingly set the width of grid column.